# Validate jQuery file upload preview

Tags: jquery

I use the following script to preview an image that is selected via input['file']. How can I prevent it from trying to display files that are not images?

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if (/image/.test(input.files[0].type)) {
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```